# Is there a closed form of the Laplace Limit Constant: $x$ such that $\frac{xe^{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+1}=1$ using library functions?

Tags: special-functions, inverse, closed-form, constants, transcendental-equations

The [**Laplace Limit Constant $\lambda$**](https://oeis.org/A033259) is well know constant which is the $y$ value of the global extrema of:

$$x\,\text{sech}(x):$$

[image]

Therefore:

$$x=\max(x\,\text{sech}(x))=-\min(x\,\text{sech}(x))=1.19967…\implies y= 1.19967… \text{sech}(1.19967… )=\lambda= 0.6627434193491815809747420971092…$$

Similarly, the Laplace Limit is also the radius of convergence of the [Lagrange Inversion Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) solution for [Kepler’s Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation) with the following [expansion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_limit). Note there are other interpretations of the constant:

$$E-\epsilon\sin(E)=M\implies E = M \;+\; \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{\varepsilon^n}{2^{n-1}\,n!} \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} (-1)^k\,\binom{n}{k}\,(n-2k)^{n-1}\,\sin((n-2k)\,M)$$

converging if

$$\epsilon<\lambda$$

It can be shown that:

$$\lambda=x:\frac{xe^\sqrt{x^2+1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+1}=1$$

**“Closed Form $1$”:**

Now define $\sqrt{x^2+1}=u$:

$$e^{2u}=\frac{u+1}{u-1}\implies u=\frac12\ln\left(\frac{u+1}{u-1}\right)=\coth^{-1}(u)\implies \coth(\sqrt{x^2+1})=\sqrt{x^2+1}$$

so the Laplace Limit is a transformed [fixed point](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FixedPoint.html) of the hyperbolic cotangent. Note that:

$$\coth(u)=u\iff\cot(iu)=-iu\mathop\implies^{iu=v}\cot(v)+v=0\iff-\sqrt{\frac2{\pi v}}\left(\frac{\cos(v)}v+\sin(v)\right)=\text Y_\frac32(v)=0$$

Where appears the [BesselY function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html). Now use the [**Bessel Y Zeroes function $\text y_{n,k}\implies \text Y_n(\text y_{n,k})=0$**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BesselYZero.html) where $k\in\Bbb N$ gives the $k$th largest root even though Wolfram Alpha sometimes evaluates the function with real $k$:

$$\text Y_\frac32(v)=0 \implies \boxed{x=\lambda,\pm i\sqrt{\text y_{\frac32,k\in\Bbb N}^2+1}}$$

[**Which are solutions**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=modulus%28%28-i+sqrt%28besselyzero%283%2F2%2C7%29%5E2%2B1%29%29exp%28sqrt%28%28-i+sqrt%28besselyzero%283%2F2%2C7%29%5E2%2B1%29%29%5E2%2B1%29%29%2F%28sqrt%28%28-i+sqrt%28besselyzero%283%2F2%2C7%29%5E2%2B1%29%29%5E2%2B1%29%2B1%29-1%29). Even though we have infinite solutions for $\frac{xe^\sqrt{x^2+1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+1}=1$, they are all complex and not the real solution for the equation, which would be the Laplace Limit.

**Attempt 2:**

Take the [**Regularized Beta function**](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/BetaRegularized/):

$$\boxed{\frac{xe^{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+1}=1\iff\frac{\pi i}2\left(\text I_{\cosh^2(\sqrt{x^2+1})}\left(\frac32,-\frac12\right)-1\right)=0}$$

Here is the experimental result using the [**Inverse Beta Regularized Series $\text I^{-1}_z(a,b)$ from Wolfram functions**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseBetaRegularized.html) which extends the domain of the function to many values.

$$\frac{\pi i}2\left(\text I_{\cosh^2(\sqrt{x^2+1})}\left(\frac32,-\frac12\right)-1\right)=0 \implies x=\pm\sqrt{\cosh^{-1}\left(\pm\sqrt{\text I^{-1}_1\left(\frac32,-\frac12\right)}\right)^2-1}$$

$$\text I^{-1}_z(a,b)\mathop=^{a>0}(az\text B(a,b))^\frac1a+\frac{b-1}{a+1} (az\text B(a,b))^\frac 2a+ \frac{(b-1)(a^2+3ab-a+5b-4}{2(a+1)^2(a+2)}(az\text B(a,b))^\frac 3a +…$$

However, using $4$ of the terms from the series gives the [wrong number](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sqrt%5B-1+%2B+ArcCosh%5BSqrt%5Bx%5D%5D%5E2%5D%2Cx%3D+10.309376336590195772671787931918765370114237879531869%2B+0.90392685654651648019581899406237397320078208036466) for [various attempts](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sqrt%5B-1+%2B+ArcCosh%5B-Sqrt%5Bx%5D%5D%5E2%5D%2Cx%3D+10.309376336590195772671787931918765370114237879531869%2B+0.90392685654651648019581899406237397320078208036466), so we cannot use the $\text I^{-1}_z(a,b)$ function nor its expansion to get a solution. It is still possible to use this technique, but it has not worked yet.

**Conclusion:**

However, neither of these solutions gives a closed form without stretching the definition of a function or finding a different value for the Laplace Limit equation $\frac{xe^\sqrt{x^2+1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+1}=1$. Is there any closed form for the Laplace Limit using library functions, those implemented in softwares like [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/special.html) or [Wolfram Functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/) among others, besides “Laplace Limit=$\lambda$? Please correct me and give me feedback!

**Explicit series solution attempt:**

Using @Claude Leibovici’s [**reference**](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.3999.pdf) we get a possible sum representation for $\text{coth}(x_*)=x_*=\sqrt{1-\lambda^2}\implies \lambda=\sqrt{x_*^2+1}$: for some radius of convergence. See page $3$ of the link:

> $$e^x\frac{x-t}{x-s}=a\implies x= x=t+(s-t)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\text L_{n-1}^1((t-s)n)a^n}{ne^{nt}} = x=t+(s-t)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \,_1\text F_1(1-n;2; (t-s)n ) e^{-nt} a^n =t-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty \binom nk\frac{(ae^{-t})^n(n(s-t))^k}{n^2(k-1)!}$$

Therefore we should find that $x\to 2x,s=-2,t=2,a=1$:

$$\boxed{\text{coth}(x)=x\iff e^{2x}\frac{2x-2}{2x+2}=1\mathop\implies x= 1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\text L_{n-1}^1(4n)}{ne^{2n}}=1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \,_1\text F_1(1-n;2; 4n ) e^{-2n}=2-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty \binom nk\frac{4^k n^{k-2}}{(k-1)! e^{2n}} }$$

where the series [**converges**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+2+laguerrel%28n-1%2C1%2C4n%29%2F%28n+e%5E%282n%29%29+from+n%3D1+to++3000), but Wolfram Alpha mistakenly says that it diverges. Note the [Confluent Hypergeomtric function](The [**Laplace Limit Constant $\lambda$**](https://oeis.org/A033259) is well know constant which is the $y$ value of the global extrema of:  $$x\,\text{sech}(x):$$  [image]  Therefore:  $$x=\max(x\,\text{sech}(x))=-\min(x\,\text{sech}(x))=1.19967…\implies y= 1.19967… \text{sech}(1.19967… )=\lambda= 0.6627434193491815809747420971092…$$  Similarly, the Laplace Limit is also the radius of convergence of the [Lagrange Inversion Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) solution for [Kepler’s Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation) with the following [expansion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_limit). Note there are other interpretations of the constant:  $$E-\epsilon\sin(E)=M\implies E = M \;+\; \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{\varepsilon^n}{2^{n-1}\,n!} \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} (-1)^k\,\binom{n}{k}\,(n-2k)^{n-1}\,\sin((n-2k)\,M)$$  converging if   $$\epsilon<\lambda$$  It can be shown that:  $$\lambda=x:\frac{xe^\sqrt{x^2+1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+1}=1$$  **“Closed Form $1$”:**  Now define $\sqrt{x^2+1}=u$:  $$e^{2u}=\frac{u+1}{u-1}\implies u=\frac12\ln\left(\frac{u+1}{u-1}\right)=\coth^{-1}(u)\implies \coth(\sqrt{x^2+1})=\sqrt{x^2+1}$$  so the Laplace Limit is a transformed [fixed point](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FixedPoint.html) of the hyperbolic cotangent. Note that:  $$\coth(u)=u\iff\cot(iu)=-iu\mathop\implies^{iu=v}\cot(v)+v=0\iff-\sqrt{\frac2{\pi v}}\left(\frac{\cos(v)}v+\sin(v)\right)=\text Y_\frac32(v)=0$$  Where appears the [BesselY function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html). Now use the [**Bessel Y Zeroes function $\text y_{n,k}\implies \text Y_n(\text y_{n,k})=0$**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BesselYZero.html) where $k\in\Bbb N$ gives the $k$th largest root even though Wolfram Alpha sometimes evaluates the function with real $k$:   $$\text Y_\frac32(v)=0 \implies \boxed{x=\lambda,\pm i\sqrt{\text y_{\frac32,k\in\Bbb N}^2+1}}$$  [**Which are solutions**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=modulus%28%28-i+sqrt%28besselyzero%283%2F2%2C7%29%5E2%2B1%29%29exp%28sqrt%28%28-i+sqrt%28besselyzero%283%2F2%2C7%29%5E2%2B1%29%29%5E2%2B1%29%29%2F%28sqrt%28%28-i+sqrt%28besselyzero%283%2F2%2C7%29%5E2%2B1%29%29%5E2%2B1%29%2B1%29-1%29). Even though we have infinite solutions for $\frac{xe^\sqrt{x^2+1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+1}=1$, they are all complex and not the real solution for the equation, which would be the Laplace Limit.   **Attempt 2:**  Take the [**Regularized Beta function**](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/BetaRegularized/):  $$\boxed{\frac{xe^{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+1}=1\iff\frac{\pi i}2\left(\text I_{\cosh^2(\sqrt{x^2+1})}\left(\frac32,-\frac12\right)-1\right)=0}$$  Here is the experimental result using the [**Inverse Beta Regularized Series $\text I^{-1}_z(a,b)$ from Wolfram functions**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseBetaRegularized.html) which extends the domain of the function to many values.   $$\frac{\pi i}2\left(\text I_{\cosh^2(\sqrt{x^2+1})}\left(\frac32,-\frac12\right)-1\right)=0 \implies x=\pm\sqrt{\cosh^{-1}\left(\pm\sqrt{\text I^{-1}_1\left(\frac32,-\frac12\right)}\right)^2-1}$$   $$\text I^{-1}_z(a,b)\mathop=^{a>0}(az\text B(a,b))^\frac1a+\frac{b-1}{a+1} (az\text B(a,b))^\frac 2a+ \frac{(b-1)(a^2+3ab-a+5b-4}{2(a+1)^2(a+2)}(az\text B(a,b))^\frac 3a +…$$  However, using $4$ of the terms from the series gives the [wrong number](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sqrt%5B-1+%2B+ArcCosh%5BSqrt%5Bx%5D%5D%5E2%5D%2Cx%3D+10.309376336590195772671787931918765370114237879531869%2B+0.90392685654651648019581899406237397320078208036466) for [various attempts](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sqrt%5B-1+%2B+ArcCosh%5B-Sqrt%5Bx%5D%5D%5E2%5D%2Cx%3D+10.309376336590195772671787931918765370114237879531869%2B+0.90392685654651648019581899406237397320078208036466), so we cannot use the $\text I^{-1}_z(a,b)$ function nor its expansion to get a solution. It is still possible to use this technique, but it has not worked yet.  **Conclusion:**  However, neither of these solutions gives a closed form without stretching the definition of a function or finding a different value for the Laplace Limit equation $\frac{xe^\sqrt{x^2+1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+1}=1$. Is there any closed form for the Laplace Limit using library functions, those implemented in softwares like [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/special.html) or [Wolfram Functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/) among others, besides “Laplace Limit=$\lambda$? Please correct me and give me feedback!  **Explicit series solution attempt:**  Using @Claude Leibovici’s [**reference**](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.3999.pdf) we get a possible sum representation for $\text{coth}(x_*)=x_*=\sqrt{1-\lambda^2}\implies \lambda=\sqrt{x_*^2+1}$: for some radius of convergence. See page $3$ of the link:  >$$e^x\frac{x-t}{x-s}=a\implies x= x=t+(s-t)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\text L_{n-1}^1((t-s)n)a^n}{ne^{nt}} = x=t+(s-t)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \,_1\text F_1(1-n;2; (t-s)n ) e^{-nt} a^n =t-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty \binom nk\frac{(ae^{-t})^n(n(s-t))^k}{n^2(k-1)!}$$  Therefore we should find that $x\to 2x,s=-2,t=2,a=1$:  $$\boxed{\text{coth}(x)=x\iff e^{2x}\frac{2x-2}{2x+2}=1\mathop\implies x= 1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\text L_{n-1}^1(4n)}{ne^{2n}}=1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \,_1\text F_1(1-n;2; 4n ) e^{-2n}=2-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty \binom nk\frac{4^k n^{k-2}}{(k-1)! e^{2n}} }$$  where the series [**converges**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+2+laguerrel%28n-1%2C1%2C4n%29%2F%28n+e%5E%282n%29%29+from+n%3D1+to++3000), but Wolfram Alpha mistakenly says that it diverges. Here is the real solution, the Laplace Limit: with rewritten

Here is the real solution, the Laplace Limit:

$$\boxed{\lambda=\left(1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \,_1\text F_1(1-n;2; 4n ) e^{-2n}\right)\text{sech}\left(1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \,_1\text F_1(1-n;2; 4n ) e^{-2n}\right) =\sqrt{\left(1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\text L_{n-1}^1(4n)}{ne^{2n}} \right)^2-1}}$$

The squared sums could be rewritten. Maybe we can simplify?

Comment: $\lambda=\sqrt{x^2_*-1}$ is even simpler.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes, but then there would be no defined function, which gives a closed form. However, $x_*$ just means zeroes which can be used to solve any problem like $e^x+\sin(x)=0\implies x=x_*$

Comment: Have a look at the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $f(x)=x\, \text{sech}(x)$ is, as you wrote, maximum when
$$(x-1)\,e^x=(x+1)\,e^{-x} \implies e^{-2x}=\frac{x-1}{x+1}$$  So, more than likely, the only solution is given in terms of [the generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equation $(4)$ in the linked paper). So, from a formal point of view, there is a closed form for this constant.

In fact, it looks to me better to write that
$$\lambda=\sqrt{x^2_*-1}\quad \text{where} \quad x_*\tanh(x_*)-1=0$$ Using series expansion around $x=a$ and then series reversion, we have $$x_*=a + t +\frac{1-a b-b^2+a b^3 }{-a-b+a b^2 }t^2+$$
$$\frac{\left(a^2+6\right)-8 a b+\left(a^2-9\right) b^2+14 a b^3+\left(3-5 a^2\right) b^4-6
   a b^5+3 a^2 b^6 }{3(-a-b+a b^2)^3 }t^3+O(t^4)$$ where $b=\tanh(a)$ and $t=\frac{1-ab}{a+b-ab^2}$.

Using this very truncated expansion and $a=2W(1)$, we have

$$x_*=1.199680\cdots$$ while the "exact" value is
$x_*= 1.199678\cdots$

This approximation would give $\lambda\sim 0.662747$ while the exact value is                  $0.662743$

**Update**

Around the solution, the function which is the closest to linearity is
$$h(x)=1- x\tanh(x)$$ So, a recursive definition of its solution $x_*$ could be
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{2 x_n^2+\cosh (2 x_n)+1}{2 x_n+\sinh (2 x_n)}\qquad \text{with}\qquad x_0=2\Omega$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.13428658082 \\
 1 & 1.19974041144 \\
 2 & 1.19967864026
\end{array}
\right)$$

---

**@AaronHendrickson's  contribution:** As pointed out by @Claude, we want the value $x_\ast$ solving
$$
1=e^{2x_\ast}\frac{x_\ast-1}{x_\ast+1}.
$$
For convenience we can make the substitution $z=2x_\ast$ so that we instead seek a solution $x_\ast=z/2$ with $z$ solving
$$
1=e^{z}\frac{z-2}{z+2}.
$$
According to the linked arXiv article we have by definition
$$
x_\ast=\frac{1}{2}W\left({2\atop -2};1\right),
$$
with $W({\mathbf t\atop\mathbf s};z)$ being the generalized Lambert function. Employing the series expansion in Theorem 4 of the linked article (using $a=1$, $t=2$, $s=-2$, and $T=4$) as well as the relation $-L^\prime_n(w)=L_{n-1}^{(1)}(w)$ gives
$$
x_\ast=1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{L_{n-1}^{(1)}(4n)}{n}e^{-2n}.
$$
This series can then be implemented in Mathematica as follows:

```
In[32]:= 1+2 NSum[LaguerreL[n-1,1,4 n]/n Exp[-2 n],{n,1,Infinity}]
Out[32]= 1.19968
```

Comment: +1 Interesting, but is this generalized Lambert w function implemented anywhere or have a reference, like in SciPy, wolfram mathworld, [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/), Wikipedia, Mathematica, [maplesoft](https://www.maplesoft.com/), etc?

Comment: @TymaGaidash. No, as far as I know. But, it is the exact formal solution only using known functions.

Comment: @TymaGaidash. In the linked paper, theu give the series expansion

Comment: +1. Also, @TymaGaidash: Maple and Mathematica both natively include the Lambert W-function.

Comment: @TravisWillse. Could you show me ? What did you do with Mathematica ? Please !!!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I don't mean that I've worked anything in particular out for the current problem. But the Lambert W-function (all of its branches) can be called with `ProductLog[k, z]` https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProductLog.html `LambertW[k, z]` was at least at one point an undocumented synonym.

Comment: The “Generalized lambert W function”, from the answerer’s article, and the $\text W_k(z)$ function have similar names, but are different ideas.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an integral representation for the fixed point of $\coth(x)$ after differentiating [integral representation](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/LaguerreLGeneral/07/01/01/0002/) of  Laguerre L and switching this integral with the sum in @Claude Leibovici’s answer:

$$\coth(x)=x\implies x=1-\frac1\pi\int_0^{2\pi}e^{ix}\ln\left(1-e^{-4e^{-ix}-2}-e^{-4e^{ix}-ix-2}\right)dx$$

[**Shown here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=coth%28x%29-x%2Cx%3D1%2BNintegrate%5B-%28e%5E%28i+x%29+log%281+-+e%5E%28-2+-+4+e%5E%28i+x%29%29+-+e%5E%28-2+-+i+x+-+4+e%5E%28i+x%29%29%29%29%2F%CF%80%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C2pi%7D%5D). One wonders about the result using [Burniston Siewert integrals](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwirscOPyo78AhUHKFkFHSXaBjQQFnoECBQQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Faip.scitation.org%2Fdoi%2F10.1063%2F1.526448&usg=AOvVaw3NiJLx_buaBJU8LgxFzDmG). Integrand plot:

[image]

Comment: If one is wondering, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3JnE.jpg) are another integral representation and a real only integrand